# filter text xml file

Tags: xml, filter

I have a big (with couple of hundred thousands records) XML file from which I'd like to filter only specific fields.
example of the file construction:

```
<A>
<id>123</id>
<B>
   <C>value1</C>
   <D>value2</D>
   ....
   <E></E>
</B>
<Z></Z>
...
<Y></Y>
<A>
```

I'd like to filter this XML file and contain only the id and the data enclosed in C and D fields.

How this can be done?

Comment: If <C>...</C> always in one line try `grep -o '<[CD]>[^<]*</[CD]>'`

Comment: A,B,..Z are just to replace the names of the actual parameter. what should be done in this case

Comment: `grep -o '<\(parameterC\|parameterD\)>[^<]*</\1>'`

Comment: I really wouldn't suggest using `grep` - `XML` is not a thing that's easily greppable, thanks to whitespace reformatting, tag nesting and unary tags. Not to mention handing broken `XML` appropriately. (e.g. you should at least detect if tags aren't closed).

Comment: well, as part of some troubleshooting, there is a need to understand some phenomena for a records which contain a big amount of data but I need only part of it. I think that the best option would be to get it into Excel so that I can see it and filter the exact values which I'm looking for. Therefore I think about performing grep on the XML.

Answer (score 4):

The [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) tool will do this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m /A -o ID, -v id -n -o C, -v //C -n -o D, -v //D -n test.xml
```

For each A under the root element (`-m /A`), it prints the string "ID," (`-o ID,`), the contents of id (`-v id`), a newline (`-n`), and likewise for children C (`-v //C`)and D (`-v //D`) with their respective headers.  The double slashes are the XPath for "anywhere under the matched node."

The result, as tested on my system, using your test file, is the comma-separated output:

```
ID,123
C,value1
D,value2
```

If you don't want the headers, omit the `-o <whatever>` arguments.

Thanks to [this article](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/xml_starlet) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question properly, we'd ideally need a better example - some *valid* xml is a good start.

Also - an example of desired output. You don't, for example, indicate where you'd want the `<C>` and `<D>` elements to end up within your resultant XML. They're *already* children of `<B>` - do you want to preserve `B` or reparent `C` and `D` to the root?

However generically reconstructing `XML` is quite easy using `XML::Twig` and `perl`.

E.g. Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my @wanted = qw ( C D id );


my %wanted = map { $_ => 1 } @wanted; 

sub delete_unwanted_tags {
   my ( $twig, $element ) = @_;
   my $tag = $element -> tag;
   if ( not $wanted{$tag} ) {
        $element -> delete;
   }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { _all_ => \&delete_unwanted_tags } );
$twig -> parse ( \*DATA );
$twig -> print;

__DATA__
<A>
<id>123</id>
<B>
   <C>value1</C>
   <D>value2</D>
   <E></E>
</B>
<Z></Z>
<Y></Y>
</A>
```

Because we haven't said "keep `<B>`" the result is:

```
<A>
  <id>123</id>
</A>
```

Adding `<B>` to the `wanted` list:

```
<A>
  <id>123</id>
  <B>
    <C>value1</C>
    <D>value2</D>
  </B>
</A>
```

If however, what you want to do is reparent `C` and `D` into `A`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my @wanted   = qw ( id);
my @reparent = qw ( C D );

#turn the above into hashes, so we can do "if $wanted{$tag}"
my %wanted   = map { $_ => 1 } @wanted;
my %reparent = map { $_ => 1 } @reparent;

sub delete_unwanted_tags {
    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_;
    my $tag = $element->tag;
    if ( not $wanted{$tag} ) {
        $element->delete;
    }
    if ( $reparent{$tag} ) {
        $element->move( 'last_child', $twig->root );
    }
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented_a',
    twig_handlers => { _all_ => \&delete_unwanted_tags }
);
$twig->parse( \*DATA );
$twig->print;

__DATA__
<A>
<id>123</id>
<B>
   <C>value1</C>
   <D>value2</D>
   <E></E>
</B>
<Z></Z>
<Y></Y>
</A>
```

Note - the "twig handler" is called at the *end* of each element (when a close tag is encountered) which is why this works - we recurse down to find `C` and `D` before we finish processing (and deleting) `B`.

This produces:

```
<A>
  <id>123</id>
  <C>value1</C>
  <D>value2</D>
</A>
```

In the above, I have used `__DATA__`, `\*DATA` and `parse` because it allows me to illustrate both the XML and techiques. You should probably use instead `parsefile('my_file.xml')` instead of `parse(\*DATA)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use lxgrep from the ltXML2 toolkit (Edinburgh University), eg

```
$ lxgrep -w A '(id|C|D)' test.xml
<A>
<id>123</id>
<C>value1</C>
<D>value2</D>
</A>
```

Using these kinds of tool is *far* faster and more reliable than rolling your own.

---

XML FAQ: http://xml.silmaril.ie/